# aggregate data table in r

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a large data table which need to be aggregated by one variable (ID). Variable Vb should be aggregated as a sum, but variable Vc should just keep it's value since it has the same value for each ID(similar to aggregation by first value in SPSS).

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 44, 55, 55, 55), 
    Vb=c(50,40,4,3,2,8,9,11,5), Vc = c(1,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,2))
```

I have approximately 15 variables to aggregate (half of them by sum, others by value), so the most efficient way would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (if Vc is truly unique):

```
DT[, .(Vb=sum(Vb), Vc=unique(Vc)), by=ID]
```

Comment: You can just use `Vc[1]` instead of `unique(VC)`, or pass `Vc` to by `DT[, sum(Vb), .(ID, Vc)]`

Comment: This is the best way to do this on a data.table. If you want to aggregate by multiple values, use by = .(ID1, ID2). here the . is equivalent to list, and the output is a data.table with columns specified. I would maybe suggest putting variables like vb in the by, which would cover for them not being unique in places.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

We can `group by ID` and `sum(Vb)` as below:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select ID,sum(Vb),VC from DT group by ID") # If Vc is unique
```

**OR**

```
sqldf("select ID,sum(Vb),VC from DT group by ID,Vc") # If Vc is not unique
```

Output:

```
  ID sum(Vb) Vc
1 11      90  1
2 22       9  3
3 44       8  1
4 55      25  2
```